# Creating an Array of type String with 10 inputs

Tags: java, arrays, string, new-operator

I wanted to practice with array and I don't get why it doesn't print the following out:
The problem is that the terminal outputs: null
Why is that and what did I do wrong?

```
package Practice;

public class CreatingArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] women = { "persian", "palestinian", "german", "russian", "spanish", "italian", "greek", "hungarian",
                "brazilian", "turkish" };
        women = new String[10];

        System.out.println(women[8]);

    }
}
```

Comment: `women = new String[10]` creates a NEW EMPTY array and associates to `women` variable , just remove that line

Answer (score 1):

You are re-assigning women to be an empty string[10] before printing to console.
Remove `women = new String[10];` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] women = { "persian", "palestinian", "german", "russian",
"spanish", "italian", "greek", "hungarian","brazilian", "turkish" };

System.out.println(women[8]);
```

Will work for you.